# CrateDB 3.3 - Can't get COPY FROM to import a CSV file in Windows

Tags: cratedb

I'm getting errors attempting to import a csv on Windows, can someone provide the correct syntax?

I'm trying this:  copy checking from 'file://C:\Users\jdoe\Downloads\testfile.csv' return summary;

and variations and get a 'SQLActionException[SQLParseException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: file://C:\Users\jdoe\Downloads\testfile.csv]

Thanks, Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add backslash and forward slash (and change others to forward slashes) after drive letter as per this [documentation](https://crate.io/docs/crate/reference/en/latest/sql/statements/copy-from.html#file). So something along the lines of
`copy checking from 'file://C:\/Users/jdoe/Downloads/testfile.csv' return summary`